# Is it part of an offical set?

Tags: set-identification

Does this assembly look familiar to anyone? I've identified the two trans-light blue 4x1 tiles and looked up and down [the list on Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2431&in=S) but none of them look right.

[image: the mysterious assembly]

Comment: There are no sets with both [the transparent 1x4 tile](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2431&colorID=15&in=A) and [the transparent 1x2 plate](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3023&colorID=15&in=A). If it's part of a set, it's been modified.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Have you got a tool for finding sets that contain a list of pieces? I've seen Rebrickable's API but haven't gotten around to writing any code against it. P.S. you should write that as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: I haven't tried the Rebrickable API. I just checked it myself manually from the Bricklink lists.

Comment: Is it me or are the transparent blue parts different colours? Looks like the [1x2 plate is Transparent Blue](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4260426), while the [1x4 tile is Transparent Light Blue](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-4586557)? In which case only [2016 LEGO City Advent Calendar](https://brickset.com/sets/60133-1/City-Advent-Calendar) contains both, and that's clearly not right.

Comment: If you combine the black 2x4 slope with the 1x4 tile the best fit is 70228 "Vultrix's Sky Scavenger", but that doesn't have any transparent grey slopes in it.

Answer (score 3):

You could cross-check the sets with the [transparent 1 x 4 tile](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2431&colorID=15&in=A) and the [transparent 1 x 2 plate](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3023&colorID=15&in=A). No matches jump out at me.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any tools to make crosschecking easier.

Comment: Using those two lists you provided I found there are the following sets with both pieces 21021 Marina Bay Sands https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21021-1#T=I, 70145 Maula's Ice Mammoth https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70145-1#T=I, 70165 Ultra Agent's Missions HQ https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70165-1#T=I, 76041 Hydra Fortress Smash https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76041-1, 76042 The SHIELD Helicarrier and a few more https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76042-1

Comment: @Craig Huh, I must have made a mistake in crosschecking.